# Doubt about the optimal constant in a functional inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-analysis

Set $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and define $F(x)=\vert u (x)\vert ^2 x$.By the divergence theorem, $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} div\ F(x)\ dx = 0 \Rightarrow  \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} (\overline{u}(x)\nabla u(x) + u(x)\nabla\overline{u}(x) + N |u(x)|^2 )\ dx = 0 $$ equivalently,
$$ N\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|u(x)|^2\ dx = -2  \text{Re} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}(\overline{u}(x)\nabla u(x))\cdot x\ dx  $$ Taking module and applying Hölder inequality one gets
$$   N\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|u(x)|^2\ dx  \leq 2 \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \vert u(x)\vert ^2 \vert x \vert ^2  \ dx\right)^{1/2}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \vert \nabla u(x)\vert ^2   \ dx\right)^{1/2} $$
that is,
$$    \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|u(x)|^2\ dx  \leq \frac{2}{N} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \vert u(x)\vert ^2 \vert x \vert ^2  \ dx\right)^{1/2}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \vert \nabla u(x)\vert ^2   \ dx\right)^{1/2} $$
So I want to find a function or functions where the equality holds in the above inequality. From the proof, it seems that I must require that $\overline{u}\nabla u = u\nabla \overline{u}$ (this is the same to require that $\overline{u}(x)\nabla u(x) \in \mathbb{R}$) and that the equality holds when applying Hölder inequality, that is $\vert u(x)\vert^2\vert x \vert ^2 = \lambda |\nabla u(x)|^2$ a.e. on $\mathbb{R}^N$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

Am I wrong or missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it always the case that $\mathrm{div} (x|u(x)|^2)=0$?

Comment: By divergence theorem, we have that the integral over all the space of $div (x|u|^2)$ is zero, not that $div (x|u|^2)$ is zero. Just think that $u$ is $\mathcal{C}^\infty _0 (\mathbb{R}^N)$ and apply divergence theorem on $B(0,R)$. Then since $u$ has compact support, the integral over the boundary is zero for big enough $R$.

Comment: Oh yes, of course, sorry, that was a silly question.

Comment: Before applying Cauchy-Schwarz you also implicitly do this: $$|u\nabla u \cdot x|\le |u||\nabla u||x|.$$ Could it be that you lose something at this step?

Comment: Mmm and isn't it also Cauchy-Schwarz ? It is similar to $$ \vert\langle x , y\rangle \vert \leq \Vert x \Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert$$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^N$

Comment: It seems I get $u(x)=c\Vert x\Vert$ where c is a positive constant... but that function ir not $L^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^N

Comment: I am answering in the chat room.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro is chat still alive?

Comment: Note that equality holds for the functions $u(x)=Ce^{-\Vert x\Vert /2}$ for every constant C. Are there more functions that where equality hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is going on with that chat.

Anyway, good find, Gaussians $u(x)=Ce^{-|\mu x|^2}$, with $C\in\mathbb C,  \mu\in\mathbb R$,  extremize that inequality. They are also solutions to the differential equation $|u(x)|^2|x|^2=\lambda |\nabla u(x)|^2$, so my concerns were unfounded.

I think that Gaussians are the only *radial* and smooth maximizers, because the differential equation reduces, in the radial case, to $$r^2u^2=\lambda (u')^2, $$ and the inequality is scale invariant, so we can apply a scaling transformation to reduce to the $\lambda=1$ case. In other words, up to scaling, all maximizers must satisfy the differential equation with $\lambda=1$. And since the maximizers are assumed to be smooth, it must be the case that $u'(0)=0$. We now have a single first-order differential equation with one boundary condition: thus, there is only one solution.

Thus, the only radial and smooth maximizer is, up to scaling, a rescaled Gaussian.

**EDIT**. This inequality is exactly the *uncertainty inequality* of Fourier analysis:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle

In dimension $1$, the only extremizers are Gaussians, I think that the same thing holds in all dimension.